# How to plot lines on image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm struggling with a problem here when trying to plotting multiple lines on an image. So, this is my code:

```
fig=plt.figure()
final = cv2.imread('frame9.jpg')
for p in polar:
    plt.plot([0,1],[p[0],p[0]],c='red')
plt.imshow(final,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

My *polar* ndarray:

```
[[ 7.28073704e+01 -1.60300574e-02  3.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.68751118e+02 -2.28065027e-02  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.10662349e+02 -3.40033470e-02  6.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.20656915e+02 -1.65935831e-02  5.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.28887705e+01 -8.43417664e-04  5.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.27472877e+01 -7.25424861e-03  2.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.09924214e+02 -1.81133209e-02  3.00000000e+00]
 [ 5.85000000e+01  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.57589902e+02 -1.70840018e-02  3.00000000e+00]]
```

The result shows just the original image without any lines on it.
Is this because of the *polar* ndarray? Or anything else? Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lines are drawn by default on top of images, the order of calling the draw function doesn't matter here.

To draw something on an image, it is important to know the coordinates of the image. To this end, [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) has an `extent=` parameter with the limits in x and in y direction. The exact coordinates of your image aren't clear from the question, so I used some arbitrary values for the example.

`imshow` forces the aspect ratio to be equal to the extents. This way, photos and maps aren't deformed. But for calculated values you often don't want such fixed aspect ratio. You can change it with `aspect='auto'`.

Also note that default images are drawn with the origin at the top, as this is standard for most image formats. Sometimes, for drawing on top it can be needed to have the origin at the bottom (`origin='lower'` vs `origin='upper'`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

polar = np.array([[7.28073704e+01, -1.60300574e-02, 3.00000000e+00],
                  [1.68751118e+02, -2.28065027e-02, 4.00000000e+00],
                  [2.10662349e+02, -3.40033470e-02, 6.00000000e+00],
                  [1.20656915e+02, -1.65935831e-02, 5.00000000e+00],
                  [2.28887705e+01, -8.43417664e-04, 5.00000000e+00],
                  [1.27472877e+01, -7.25424861e-03, 2.00000000e+00],
                  [1.09924214e+02, -1.81133209e-02, 3.00000000e+00],
                  [5.85000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00],
                  [1.57589902e+02, -1.70840018e-02, 3.00000000e+00]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
final = 10-np.random.rand(500,500).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
# final = cv2.imread('frame9.jpg')
plt.imshow(final, cmap=plt.cm.gray, extent=[0, 10, 0,  polar[:,0].max()], aspect='auto', origin='lower')
for p in polar:
    plt.plot([0, 1], [p[0], p[0]], c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: thanks, finally I did it. So interesting that the problem is all about the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you're first drawing the lines and then showing the image, thus the image is overwriting the drawn lines.

Just changing the order as follows should work:

```
fig=plt.figure()
final = cv2.imread('frame9.jpg')
plt.imshow(final,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
for p in polar:
    plt.plot([0,1],[p[0],p[0]],c='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did try to change the order like you said, but actually the problem is what @JohanC said above. Because I plot the pair of [x1,x2] just equal to [0,1] so actually the lines did plotted, but they were too short and looks like they were not there. So when I changed to `plt.plot([0,320],[p[0],p[0]],c='red')` , those lines appeared.

Comment: @KhoaLearnToCode Oh, thank you for letting me know, this is indeed surprising